# Why does Tomcat 9 have established connections on localhost

Tags: socket, tomcat9

I'm trying to understand why Apache Tomcat 9 has certain established connections that are via localhost. I'm using the Apache Tomcat 9 on windows. See below, I'm looking at the TCP/IP section in process explorer for the Tomcat9.exe process.

What caused these sockets to be established?

[image: tomcat 9 tcp/ip]

Answer (score 2):

Some environments - such as Java and Tomcat by extension - tend use the loopback address for inter process communication. That's the most likely cause.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537375/when-doing-ipc-using-tcp-ip-sockets-using-the-loopback-address-do-common-networ